# Stopping Pages from Moving on Touch

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Question about creating pages in jQuery Mobile.  I've created a mobile site... if you touch the first page of my site and move your finger side to side, the page does not shift around on the screen.  However, if you move to the second page of my site, touch the screen and move your finger side to side, it seems like the whole window moves back and forth.

Ideally, I'd like to make everything "locked" on the screen so this shifting does not take place.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Do you have to change orientation to create the issue or does it happen when you stay in the same orientation and change pages?

Comment: This happens when I stay in the same orientation and change pages.

I'm actually using a few CSS files for this mobile site. When I remove one of them, the issue disappears.  Are there specific settings that cause this type of (mis)behavior?

Comment: Can you post the CSS in the style-sheet that when removed fixes the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=320, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
```

Comment: Better to declare the width as `width=device-width` surely ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it.  It was the first thing I tried.  It's literally like the entire Safari window moves around, not just the page on that Safari window.